# Can the Alexa ask-cli be used to set account linking information?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, particle.io

I'm rewriting an Alexa skill that communicates with the Particle.io API. This time I'm using the ask-cli to manage the uploads. So my basic process so far has been:

1. "ask new" to create a starter skill and lambda
2. "ask deploy" to create the Alexa skill and lambda
3. Run the new skill to verify the initial set of files work ok.
4. Modify the files created in the first step
5. "ask deploy" to upload any changes
6. Loop back to step 3 to test, update, redeploy.

This is all working very nicely. However, this skill needs to use account linking to allow the user to log into their Particle.io account in order for the skill to send commands to the user's IoT devices.

I cannot find any information about adding Account Linking information to any of the files that "ask deploy" uploads. I am able to manually add the account linking information using the website, and that works correctly, but I'd really like to use the ask-cli so that my updates can be tracked on git.

Does anyone know if and/or how to set account linking information using the ask-cli?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#create-account-linking-subcommand

Try this:

```
ask-cli api --skill-id SOMESKILLID create-account-linking
```

It's an interactive method of setting up the account linking, there isn't a pure cli/data way to do it automatically unfortunately (yet).

Comment: Wow, I skimmed right over that api command when reading the doc. Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 0):

The create-account-linking isn't valid anymore.
You have to use [update-account-linking-info](https://developer.amazon.com/en-GB/docs/alexa/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#update-account-linking-info-subcommand) to create/update the account linking on the skill

```sh
ask smapi update-account-linking-info -s amzn1.ask.skill.xxx \
  -g development \
  --account-linking-request "$(cat ./accountLinking.json)"
```

accountLinking.json (example with LWA)

```json
{
  "accountLinkingRequest": {
    "accessTokenScheme": "HTTP_BASIC",
    "accessTokenUrl": "https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token",
    "authorizationUrl": "https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa",
    "clientId": "xxx",
    "clientSecret": "xxx",
    "domains": [],
    "scopes": ["profile"],
    "skipOnEnablement": true,
    "type": "AUTH_CODE"
  }
}
```